# Is there a way to add color to borders of table using kable extra in rmarkdown pdf?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, kableextra

I want full borderd table and make the lines of border to be green. i didn't find any attributes to make the lines to greeen in column_spec or row_spec.

```
'kbl(df,booktabs = T,longtable = T,align = c("l", "c", "c", "c")) %>%
kable_styling(latex_options = c("hold_position","repeat_header"),bootstrap_options = "bordered",full_width = F)%>%
  column_spec(1, width = "8.5cm",border_left = T, border_right = T)%>%
  column_spec(2:4, width = "2.5cm", border_right = T)%>%
  collapse_rows(latex_hline = "full")%>%
  row_spec(0, bold = T, color = "white", background = "#008752")
```

how can i remove gap between the border lines

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
\usepackage{colortbl}
\arrayrulecolor{green}
```

to your header includes to change the line colour to green

Comment: can I use color code inplace of green  there

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I think? that it is something like this https://www.color-hex.com/

Comment: actually i need to maintain same color throughout the pdf  "#008752"

Comment: Ah, hex colours. Sure: `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}\definecolor{mycolour}{HTML}{008752}\arrayrulecolor{mycolour}`

Comment: or even `\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{008752}`

Comment: Thanq. one last question i'm getting borders lines in discrete. but not continuous for that also do i need to use any other package.

Comment: no idea what you might mean without either a [mre] or an image

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz added image to question there is a  gap near intersection of horizontal and vertical lines i have circled. can i remove those gaps . can you please check the image

Comment: The gapes come from the `booktabs` package. The philosophy of this package is that one should not use vertical lines at all. See its documentation for example of good looking tables: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf

Comment: Thank You. @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I will check that